# Why does Xdebug fail to load in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

I followed the instructions to install Xdebug in Visual Studio Codo but it fails to load.  I cut and paste my `phpinfo()` information into the installer as instructed and downloaded the advised dll which moved to the correct directory.  I changed my php.ini file and added the following line:

```ini
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll"
```

Restarted both Visual Studio Code and XAMPP but Xdebug still failed to load.

Can anybody help?

Comment: There is no need to restart Visual Studio for this. Xdebug is an extension to PHP. What did the error message really say? Do you have that file on that location? What is the output of phpinfo()'s (first section)?

Comment: XAMPP means Apache which should normally use TS (Thread Safe) build of PHP. Xdebug must match that as well. You are using NTS Xdebug build. Would be good to see the top part of your `phpinfo()` output and what that Installer/Wizard tells you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses.  Unfortunately my principle laptop has developed a suspected fault and is away for repair.  On my backup laptop I've been able to get Xdebug to run and listen on the local machine.  The next step, I think is to run a PHP file on a remote server and use Xdebug to help with debugging.  I was wondering if anybody had any insights into what I need to do to set up the remote server for debugging with Xdebug

Comment: You should follow steps in following [URL](https://tighten.co/blog/configure-vscode-to-debug-phpunit-tests-with-xdebug).

Its a great explanation.